# MySql password doesn't work after restarting windows

Tags: mysql

I'm having an awkward issue here. I've recently installed MySql on windows 7. Based on things I have googled, when you first install MySQL it shouldn't ask for a password. For some reason it did on my system.

I used the method described in the link below to reset my root password:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

It works. However apparently the password is lost every time I restart windows. Therefore I have to reset the root password every time I restart windows. 
Any Ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Additional notes:**

When I type

```
--init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

in the command window, I get the message "starting process 1960...." however it apparently freezes there and I won't be able enter further input into the command window. However when I open the MySQL workbench everything works fine.

On the other hand when I use this:

```
mysqld
         --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\my.ini"
         --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

The command window doesn't freeze, but when I open the MySQL workbench I can't connect.

**Additional notes2:**

After following the steps in the link if I try to start the service from the "Services" window I get an error:

```
Windows could not start the MySQL 5.6 service on local computer. Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly.
```

Again everything works fine if I manually open the MySQL workbench, however I do get this error when trying to start the service.

Comment: We can't know exactly what you're doing because we cannot see you doing it, and you've not provided the steps you're following in detail.

Comment: Have you made sure that the identity that MySQL is running under has write access to C:\mysql-init.txt ? Windows 7 does not allow normal users write access to the root of C:. The better option would be to put the file somewhere like C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\.

Comment: yes I even moved it to another drive but still having the same issue